# How to test similarity between multiple medical differential diagnoses?

Tags: similarities, cohens-kappa, kendall-tau, concordance

I have multiple observations collected by doctors where they give the differential diagnoses, the 10 most probable diseases (d). I want to calculate the inter-observer similarity.

my data looks like this
case 1:
doc1 = [d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9,d10] 
doc2 = [d3,d12,d1,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9,d10] 
doc3 = [d1,d4,d13,d14,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9,d10] \

case 2: ...

I have looked at different methods such as kappa coefficient or the Kendall's W but nothing seems to 100%match what I need. For example, I can't use Kendall with incomplete blocks because it states that each disease should be ranked the same amount of times (which is not the case, like d12 in ex above)

What in your opinion should be the test that I could use?